# Socket server en App con C# Xamarin Forms

Tags: server, xamarinforms

Estoy intentando programar una App en visual studio siguiendo el modelo MVVM para enviar datos de un teléfono a otro mediante sockets con la misma App. Hasta ahora he conseguido hacer la parte de cliente y conectar con un server creado en CMD, pero cuando hago el Server en la App lo que ocurre es la aplicacion no carga. No se puede realizar recarga activa de Xaml y cuando compilo e implemento por separado la aplicación no responde. He intentado lo siguiente:

```
           Texto = "Aun no se ha mandado nada";
            Socket listen = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            Socket conexion;
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAdress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint connect = new IPEndPoint(ipAdress, 2000);
            listen.Bind(connect);
            listen.Listen(6);
            conexion = listen.Accept();
            Text = "Conectado";
            byte[] recibir_info = new byte[100];
            string data = "";
            int array_size = 0;
            array_size = conexion.Receive(recibir_info, 0, recibir_info.Length, 0);
            Array.Resize(ref recibir_info, array_size);
            data = Encoding.Default.GetString(recibir_info);
            Wait = data;
```

Esto está dentro del constructor de la ViewModel de la página de Inicio que carga la MainViewModel. El problema está en `conexion = listen.Accept()` que es cuando se viene abajo la película.Tengo habilitado el permiso de internet en la aplicación porque la intención es que el servidor esté ecuchando desde que se inicie la ViewModel todo el tiempo. Si tienen algún ejemplo de aplicación que realizara esto estaría muy agradecido.

Un saludo y gracias.